# Can you hide Club posts from your Community feed?

Tags: xbox-one

I have the current XB1 preview program update that includes Clubs. I've joined one that has thousands of members, and the club's posts have inconveniently **saturated** my Community (Home screen) feed, burying my friend's posts so far down I might as well go look at each of *their* feeds (which would be a different kind of inconvenient).

I'd still like to be a member so I can post to that club, but it's a little obnoxious to not have a useful Community feed anymore.

I couldn't find much documentation on the topic, and I dont see any type of club settings to mess around with either. Is there any way to join a club and hide its posts from your Community (Home screen) activity feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know how to do it from a PC with the Xbox Preview.

1. In the Beta Xbox App (if you don't have the beta, [download it here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/xbox-beta/9nblggh1j27h)), Click on the Clubs icon on the left hand side

[image]

2. Click on the club you want to turn off seeing posts from them / in that club

[image]

3. Click on the Info tab, then click more and select unfollow

[image]

By unfollowing that club, you should no longer see **new** posts from them but you will still remain a member of that club.

Keep in mind, that your feed will still contain posts that hit your feed from this club prior to unfollowing.

Comment: That looks like what I want to do, but im a little confused, can you be a member, but not follow?

Comment: Correct.  I am currently a member of the club TrueAchievements but I no longer follow their posts

Comment: Awesome! Tested and confirmed.